# Python loop or output - only on my computer

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I have a strange problem that my computer reacts differently to this python script than other people's computer (im on macOX Mountain Lion python v =2.7) .  Any idea how to fix this, or please report the output on your system?
I only get one line of output while others seem to get all the lines properly.  Unfortunately, it won't work on my system, and i'm the one who needs it to work.  My system prints the final line of the table that is being crawled:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#file_name = "/users/ripple/uspc-cpc.txt"
#file = open(file_name,"w")
i=125
while i==125:
    url = "http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us" + str(i) + "tocpc.html"
    print 'Grabbing from: ' + url + '\n'
    i += 1
    #get the table data from the page
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    #send to beautiful soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    table = soup.find("table", width='80%')
    for tr in table.findAll('tr')[2:]:
        col = tr.findAll('td')
        #print 'hi'
        uspc = col[0].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","")
        cpc1 = col[1].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","")
        cpc2 = col[2].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","")
        cpc3 = col[3].get_text().encode('ascii','ignore').replace(" ","").replace("more...", "")
        record = uspc + ',' + cpc1 + ',' + cpc2 + ',' + cpc3 + '\n'
        print record
        #file.write(record)

#file.close()
```

Comment: Works for me on linux.

Comment: @QuentinEngles: Given that the OP explicitly says it works on everyone's computer except for his OS X Mountain Lion box, how helpful is that comment?

Comment: Beautiful Soup can use a variety of different parsers, depending on what's installed. It's likely that you have some buggy or just complicated HTML, and you're getting different results because it's using a different parser on your computer than the others you tested (e.g., it's using `html.parser` for you but `lxml` for them, or it's using `html.parser` for both but you're running Python 2.7.2 and they're running 2.7.3 or 2.7.4, or…). Can you get access to the other computers to run some tests?

Comment: @abarmert I posted that comment right before the op edited his answer by adding the system he uses. Also the specification in the question was "Please report the output on your system."

Comment: Building on what @abarnert mentioned, you are keying off table with width=80%.  Maybe there is another element that matches these criteria on the page.  See if you can't come up with a more specific locator.

Comment: @sr2222: You can download the same file he's working on. There is only one table with `width=80%`, and all of the parsers manage to find it. I suspect what's actually confusing the parsers is something stupid, like throwing out all tags with illegal `id` values, but it's hard to know without putting in some more serious debugging.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, I took a cursory look at it, but didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses. I was using the OS X text editor called TextWrangler.  I copied my code to Mac's native texteditor and pasted it back into textwrangler and the exact same code works now. Miffed, but I'm not going to argue. Could have been some indentation issue it seems.!!!  Beware that TextWrangler text editor seems to constantly cause this problem with me and also throw invisible characters into the code.

Answer (score 4):

BeautifulSoup can use a variety of different parsers. See [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for details. But the short version is:

If you have `lxml`, it uses that. If not, it tries `html5lib`. If not, it uses the stdlib `html.parser`. Different people have wildly varying versions of `lxml`, and the `libxml2` library it wraps, and `html5lib`. Plus, `html.parser` changed dramatically between Python 2.7.2 and 2.7.3 (in particular, it's much more lenient in 2.7.3).

I ran 64-bit Apple Python 2.7.2 on Mountain Lion 10.8.2 with pip-installed BS 4.1.3 using as many parsers as I had lying around, and here's what I got:

- pip-installed lxml 3.1.0 with Apple libxml2 2.7.8: 69 rows.
- pip-installed lxml 3.1.0 with Apple libxml2 2.7.8 in XML mode: 69 rows.
- pip-installed lxml 3.1.0 with Homebrew libxml2 2.9.0: 0 rows.
- pip-installed lxml 3.1.0 with Homebrew libxml2 2.9.0 in XML mode: 69 rows.
- pip-installed html5lib 0.95-dev: 0 rows.
- stdlib html.parser 2.7.2: 1 row.
- backported html.parser 2.7.4: 69 rows.

So, there's obviously something wrong with the HTML, which some parsers can handle, but others can't. To see what's wrong with it, I fed it into the [W3C online validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/cpc/html/us125tocpc.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), which found 139 errors, and could not build a semantic outline out of it.

The reason it works on some machines and not others is that bs4 is using different parsers on those machines. In particular, on your machine, you probably didn't install any third-party parsers, and you're using Apple's Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the exact same code, try deleting the .pyc

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.  I'm not sure what fixed it in the end, but I copied my code to texteditor and pasted it back into textwrangler and the exact same code works now.  Miffed, but I'm not going to argue.  Could have been some indentation issue it seems.!!!

Comment: @JosephLee: Possibly tabs mixed with spaces? I like to run with `-t` or `-tt`, especially when running random code that I downloaded or copied/pasted from the net, to let me know about those problems before I spend hours trying to debug them…